# How to link comment model to Post model django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to link a comment model to post when multiple posts are displayed in a page i want to access the post id of the post i am commenting on but i do not know how please tell me how to link the comment model
I am a begginner here so i apologize for any errors
Please comment if any more of code is needed

template :

```
{% for Img in imgs %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                <img class="activator" src="{{ Img.Post_Img.url }}" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <img src="{{ Img.op.userprofile.Profile_pic.url }}" class="profiles" alt="{{ Img.op.userprofile.Nick_Name }}">
                <span class="OP">{{ Img.op.userprofile.Nick_Name }}</span>
                <span class="card-title activator white-text text">{{ Img.Title }}<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">Vote</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal darken-4 black">
                <span class="card-title white-text text">{{ Img.Title }}<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ comment }}
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                    </button>
                </form>
                {% for comment in comments %}
                    {{ comment.op.userprofile.Nick_Name }}{{ comment.comment }}
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

models :

```
class MemeImg(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    op = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    Post_Img = CloudinaryField('Post')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title


class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(MemeImg, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    op = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    comment = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.Title
```

views ( does not work throws error not null contraint):

```
def user_home(request):
    func = data(request)
    url = func[0]
    name = func[1]
    comment = CommentSection(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = CommentSection(request.POST)
        if comment.is_valid():
            comment.save(commit=False)
            comment.op = request.user
            comment.save()
    comments = Comments.objects.all()
    imgs = MemeImg.objects.all()
    ctx = {
        'imgs': imgs,
        'url': url,
        'name': name,
        'comment': comment,
        'comments': comments,
    }
    return render(request, 'User_Home.html', ctx)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `null=True` and `blank=True` for the ForeignKey in the `Comments` model, or you must set a default value in when you `makemigrations`.

By default, `None` values aren't allowed for fields, without you explicitly allowing them, because the `post` property of the `Comments` model is set to `null=False` by default.

When you create a comment and something else you've written results in `comment.post = None`, then Django tries to find a default value. But you haven't specified a default value either, so Django raises the error because it can't find anything to fill in a field that's supposed to have something in it.

So the post field of the `Comments` model is supposed to look like:

```
 post = models.ForeignKey(MemeImg, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```